# VB.NET Manipulando um "Birthday Drop Down"

Tags: .net, vb.net, dropdown

Olá, pessoal!
Estou com dificuldades em definir uma data em um DropDown do site do Yahoo...

O link do site é: https://na.edit.yahoo.com/registration?.pd=&intl=br

Aqui o que estou tentando, mas não funciona... não sei porquê...

```
WebBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("month").SetAttribute("value", "01")
WebBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("day").SetAttribute("value", "04")
WebBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("year").SetAttribute("value", "1990")
```

Se alguém puder me dar uma força... Já tentei muitas coisas, mas esse foi o mais próximo do certo que cheguei kkkk

Enfim... Agradeço desde já!

Answer (score 0):

Seria por que o elemento `day` não tem nenhuma propriedade chamada "`value`"?

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Isso deve ser sincronizado com uma database interna lá nos servidores deles, não achei a propriedade value em nenhum dos três elementos.

Comment: Quais você acha que são minhas opções? Preciso definir esse campo das datas pelo programa...

Comment: Não sei se seria possível, poderia estudar usar Handlers para quando o usuário selecionar a caixa enviar um sinal e selecionar um valor. Eu que o `SendKeys.Send()` não funciona, tem que ser com o mouse, mas não sei fazer.